# Ubuntu won't boot most of the times when second screen is connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I hope this was a good week for everyone.

I have a problem since ubuntu 20.10 (Same for ubuntu, kubuntu, popOs and UbuntuStudio)

When booting, after grub, there's a message:

- no irq handler for vector

After that the PC simply automatically reboot.

Sometimes it get to pass that message and continue to boot, sometimes don't.
The pc most likelly will boot when i change the GPU of PCI slot a couple times, but after that it will be again unable to boot.
Another way of boot with the two screens is enter to recovery mode/Continue boot/ and restart the pc is ready, but it is the same. Sometimes work. Most of the times don't.

I already tryed to use Display port (main) + DVI (second), DVI + DVI, DVI + Display port, but none of those works.
I think is a GPU problem but i don't know how to get to the specific details of the problem.

- OS: Ubuntu-Studio (Kubuntu) 21.10 x86_64
- Host: X570 AORUS ELITE -CF
- Kernel: 5.13.0-20-lowlatency
- DE: Plasma 5.22.5
- WM: KWin
- Theme: Materia Dark [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3]
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X (24) @ 3.800GHz
- GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 5770
- Memory: 32046MiB
- Screens: HP E221 (main) + Acer AL1714(second)

Comment: What's with your power supply?

Comment: Cooler Master 750W 80+W MPE 8501 ACAAW

Comment: Whats with a dist upgrade to 21.10?

Comment: That was a clean install.